# How should this change to the inner html respond?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text of a paragraph tag with a button, and I wanted to test how different styling tags would affect that change. My html looks like this:

```
<p id="testParagraph"> This <strong> is </strong> a test </p>
<button id="button">Run Test</button>
```

In my js file, I'm grabbing that tag by its id, and trying to set its inner html like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("testParagraph").innerHtml = "I changed the inner html, but what do I look like?";
}
```

I'm not seeing any change when I click the button, and I was wondering if this was caused by something I did incorrectly, or if there's a problem with changing the html like because of the strong tag in the original paragraph tag.

Comment: The answers below correct, but also please note that this error could have been found very easily if you hit F12 and view the console any kind of invalid JavaScript would throw an error that could guide you to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been working with either of these for very long. I'll check that first from now on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("testParagraph").innerHTML = "I changed the inner html, but what do I look like?";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shseqy0t/

Answer (score 5):

It's `.innerHTML`, not `.innerHtml`. Casing is important in JavaScript.

Not much more to say. A simple typo - carry on!

**Edit:**
Since we have two identical answers though, I thought I'd give an alternative solution to the script.

You can use `addEventListener`, with a benefit being that you can attach several events to the same element (opposed to a direct `onclick`). This is not a recommendation, just mentioning that it's an alternative. Use whatever you prefer.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("testParagraph").innerHTML = "I changed the inner html, but what do I look like?";
});
```

```html
<p id="testParagraph"> This <strong> is </strong> a test </p>
<button id="button">Run Test</button>
```